# Gradle project refresh failed, cause http://downloads/.../gradle-2.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was adding a library to my project which required updating the `gradle` to `2.4.+` and when changed it and rebuilt the project, I got this error:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Please put a link to the related question

Answer (score 3):

It happens because 2.4.1 **doesn't exist.**

Check here the [full list](https://services.gradle.org/distributions).

In `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file use:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Comment: done that, now I am getting Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. in my app\build.gradle

Comment: @A_Matar It is a different issue. It seems that the build.gradle in your module hasn't the apply plugin row.Post  the issue and your build.gradle in another question or edit this topic (also if it is different)